# Weird behaviour of the down arrow key

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

On my Windows 10 laptop, here is what happens. Anywhere, it's as if the down key was typed at an irregular rythm. So on the desktop, the selected icon keeps changing downwards. In Word, the caret goes down by itself. But even more strangely, if I type the down key, the caret goes up! Am I in the twilight zone?

I tried this:

- I typed the down key several times, gently and hardly (in case it was kind of stucked).
- Scanned the laptop with Malwarebytes. It found and quarantined 19 items, but the issue persists after reboot.
- I fired the onscreen keyboard. It works correctly if I click on the arrow keys.
- I uninstalled the keyboard driver. It asked for a reboot. After the reboot, it reinstalls automatically and the problem persists.

Comment: Did you try a different (physical) keyboard?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's at my mother's home and I help her remotely. She does not have a spare usb keyboard to connect.

Comment: Have her disable the internal keyboard (https://gearupwindows.com/is-it-possible-to-disable-laptop-internal-keyboard-on-windows-10/) and then use the on-screen keyboard, https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/6-ways-to-turn-on-on-screen-keyboard-in-windows-10.html . If that eliminates the issue, keyboard replacement is often inexpensive (<US$20) and relatively painless -- see the laptop service manual.

Comment: I tried disabling (uninstalling the driver to be exact since this is the only option) the integrated keyboard, but it's not disabled until I reboot, and since rebooting reinstalls the driver, I can't test this. I won't try doing it by group policy, otherwise she won't be able to log in after rebooting. And since she has no other physical keyboard to revert to normal, it's too dangerous to try that.